# Is there a way to transpose json elements into different rows?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I don't know how to ask this so I'm going to create an example:

Suppose I have a table called "market" that consist in just two columns and three rows as follows:

[image]

So, what I want to know is if there is a way to take all the purchases products and put it in differente rows, for example:

[image]

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unnest the array into multiple rows, then you can extract the product name using the `->>` operator:

```
select t.user_id, x.purchase ->> 'product' as product
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.purchases) as x(purchase);
```

If your column is a `json` rather than `jsonb` you need to use `json_array_elements()` instead